# Change Visual Studio 2010 key binding to match eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-2010

There are plenty of people asking and solutions for going from vs to eclipse, but unfortunately I'm going the other way. I'm an eclipse fan but I have to use vs 2010 now.
Does there exist a keybindings file I can import that will give me my favorite eclipse keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use AutoHotKey. 
I am totally familiar with the pain of migrating from Eclipse to VS.
Anyway here is my AHK script. Just install AHK, edit/ this script as per your visual studio version and run it. You dont need to change anything in visual studio keybindings.

there are two ways of controlling any application on windows, either direct keyboard shortcuts with CTRL/SHIFT/ALT or using the ALT to activate menu bar and further typing F for FILE, E for EDIT and so on. The following script uses both types of shortcuts and it is up to you to decide which way you want to use the shortcuts.

I use following script for visual studio express 2012 version.

```
; ^ stands for Ctrl
; ! stands for Alt
; + stands for Shift

SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#IfWinActive, Microsoft Visual Studio Express      ;any part of the name of the window
    ^PgDn::Send ^!{PgDn}            ; next opened doc (tab navigation shortcut like in firefox/chrome)
    ^PgUp::Send ^!{PgUp}            ; previous opened doc (tab navigation shortcut like in firefox/chrome)
    ^b::Send ^{F7}                  ; compile the current file
    ^/::Send ^{e}{c}                ; comment Ctrl+e+c
    ^+/::Send ^{e}{u}               ; uncomment Ctrl+e+u
    ^k::Send ^{F3}                  ; find next Ctrl+F3
    ^w::Send ^{F4}                  ; close tab Ctrl+f4
    ^Enter::Send {F12}              ; go to defi/decl 
    ^!Enter::Send ^+{g}             ; open file under cursor (for headers) Ctrl+g
    ^+Enter::Send !{e}{i}{q}        ; show quick info Alt+e+i+q (Using menu bar)
    !Right::Send ^+{-}              ; navigate last position
    !Left::Send ^{-}                ; navigate next position    
    ^e::Send !{v}{i}                ; error window
    ^+TAB::Send !{v}{p}             ; solution explorer
                                    ; add here

    return
#IfWinActive
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only change them manually in the options I believe, but once you do you can export them for anytime you want to use them again (or release them for people who want the same keybindings). Unless of course someone wants to export their settings and give them to you.

Comment: well that's what I was getting at. Apparently lots of people have already done this for vs2010->eclipse but I was wondering if anybody had done it for those of us stuck in the other situation.